# Identify campaign members with duplicate emails

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains campaign members with over 200k records.
we have an issue where different contacts share the same email address but subscribe to different campaigns. What i need to is identify are any contacts that have a duplicate email to another contact but are not subscribed to the same set of campaigns. There are 100's of different campaigns and a contact could possibly subscribe to them all.  The table contains lots of fields but the relevant ones i need are Email which can be shared by multiple contacts, Contact_ID which is unique and case sensitive and Campaign_ID which is unique and case sensitive but can be assigned to multiple contacts.

```
+----------------------+------------+------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+
|      Email           | Contact_ID | First_Name | Last_Name | Campaign_ID | Campaign_Name |
+----------------------+------------+------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+
| John@mail.com        | 300ABC     | John       | Smith     | 100xyz      | Campaign 1    |
| Mary@mail.com        | 300abc     | Mary       | Smith     | 100wyz      | Campaign 2    |
| JonesFamily@mail.com | 300Abc     | Jim        | Jones     | 100xyz      | Campaign 1    |
| JonesFamily@mail.com | 300Abc     | Jim        | Jones     | 100Wyz      | Campaign 3    |
| JonesFamily@mail.com | 300abC     | Jane       | Jones     | 100xyz      | Campaign 1    |
| JonesFamily@mail.com | 300abC     | Jane       | Jones     | 100Wyz      | Campaign 3    |
| JonesFamily@mail.com | 300abC     | Jane       | Jones     | 100Ayz      | Campaign 4    |
+----------------------+------------+------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+
```

As per example Jim and Jane Jones share an email address and subscribe to 5 campaigns 2 are the same but Jane also Subscribes to Campaign 4. I need to script that identifies Jim and Jane as they share an email but don't subscribe to the same set of campaigns. The end goal is that we remove the email address from one contact but ensure they are subscribed to all the campaigns.

Comment: have you used `distinct`, `group by` and `having` before? In particular the last 2 together ?

Comment: My SQL knowledge is very basic. I have used distinct and group by but never having.

Comment: ok, I will wait a bit, someone will answer, else I will

Comment: How do you identify a contact?  Just by the names?

Comment: We use the Contact_ID to identify the contact as that unique to that contact where First Name, Last Name could be the same for different contacts and in some cases where there is Father and Son with the same name they could even share an email address

Comment: you might think those contact_id's are unique, it's an illusion. And if that table of yours is actually a table, and not just a view, then it is denormalized

Comment: The Contact_Id are case sensitive has this has caused us lots of issues in the past where the scripts have matched them to the incorrect contact as it didnt read them as case sensitive. it has been very frustrating

Comment: I can imagine so. Dare I ask who dreamt that one up :) If I were you, the first thing I would do would be to clean that up. A number ranging from 1 to 200k (and up) sounds good. But probably we are talking about 1 to 20k ish at the moment, right ?

Comment: They are system generated this data comes from our CRM system so it is something we cant control.

Comment: I would rip it out of mysql and do a quick c# all memory app. But that is me. Depends how exact it has to be. If not exact, then I would do it all in mysql

Comment: There is over 200K records in the table. There are about 35k unique contacts and around 700 different campaigns. Most contacts would be subscribed to more than one campaign with some subscribing to 100 or so

Comment: wish i could say more

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with `group_concat()`:

```
select email, group_concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) as commonnames
from (select email, firstname, lastname,
             group_concat(distinct campaign_id order by campaign_id) as campaigns
      from table t
      group by email, firstname, lastname
     ) en
group by email
having count(*) > 1 and min(campaigns) <> max(campaigns);
```

The subquery gets the list of campaigns for a given contact (based on the names; you might have other criteria).  The outer query then chooses emails that have more than one person where the campaigns don't match.

Comment: Jim Jones email, and Jim Jones email (identical) could be two people. Jim #2 is Jim Jr.

Comment: As @drew said Jim Jones could be different people and the contact_id is the unique identifier. The issue with it though is that it needs to be read as case sensitive because as per the example in the table the characters that make up the ID can be the same for different contacts its just some are upper or lower case

Comment: the word `just` is a poorly chosen one in this predicament @M.Milburn. In fact the word should be removed from the English language, because the speaker of it means "it should be easy, go do it", and the listener is, like, "Oh really?" I get a kick out of it everyday, in running into people :)